# Unable to check whether a field exists in a nested collection Firebase v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Sorry I'm still new to this, but I'm trying to check whether a specific field (docName) value already exists in a nested collection to perform as a condition. I'm new to v9 and I'm slowly working my way around it, but I've looked all over and I'm still unable to get the appropriate solution.

***Ref:***

```
'teachers/${uid}/contracts/autoDocID'
```

#### What I have tried

```
const Contract = async (data) => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "teachers", data.uid, "contracts"), where("docName", "==", `${data.docName}`)); 
    const condition = await getDocs(q).exists;

    if(!condition){
        //adding new doc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `await getDocs(q)` returns a [`QuerySnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot), which doesn't have an `exists` property.

Are you looking to check if the [snapshot is empty](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot.md#querysnapshotempty)?

Comment: I see what you mean, but I'm only checking whether the given input already exists within any documents under the contracts collection. I ended up solving it myself, which I've added down below. Thanks for the immediate response!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it like this:

```
const Contracts => async(data) = {
    const docRef = doc(db, "teachers", data.uid);
    const colRef = collection(docRef, "contracts");
    const q = query(collection(db, "teachers", data.uid, "contracts"), where("docName", "==", `${data.docName}`));
    const check = await getDocs(q);

    if(!check){
        await addDoc(colRef, {
            expiration: data.expiration,
            docName: data.docName,
            docUrl: data.docUrl,
        });
    } else {
        console.log('already exists')
    }
}
```